# Python - Assign value to the variable

Tags: python-3.x, iteration, global-variables, local-variables

I have a scenario in which i need to assign a value to a variable if it is None initially.

```
def sample(val,node):           
                            
    if node == None:                              
       node = val              
    else:                       
       pass      
                                                                                     
if __name__ == "__main__":      
                            
   arr = [1, 2]                
   node = None                 
                            
   for x in range(len(arr)):   
     sample(arr[x], node)
```

In the first iteration node is None, so a value is assigned. Now the node has been assigned a value. The second time when iteratred, it is still passed as None. Is it because it is passsed as a param to the sample function.

I tried removing the node paramter as below.

```
node = None               
                      
def sample(val):          
                      
   if node == None:      
     node = val        
   else:                 
     pass              
                                                
                      
if __name__ == "__main__":
                      
   arr = [1, 2]                                    
   for x in range(len(arr)):
     sample(arr[x])
```

This throws an error saying

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'node' referenced before assignment

The second time when iterated the node has to have the value 1. What needs to be done to acheive this?

Answer (score 0):

You mean

```
node = None               
                      
def sample(val):          
   global node                    
   if node is None:      
     node = val        
   else:                 
     pass              
                                                
                      
if __name__ == "__main__":
                      
   arr = [1, 2]                                    
   for x in range(len(arr)):
     sample(arr[x])  
    
   print(node)
```

Comment: If node is None am assigning a variable to the node variable. The second time when iterated, node variable is still None.

Comment: yeah thanks..can you explain why the one which i used dint work

Comment: It could not find the node variable. Setting it global in the def it could.